# Convert a Invalid JSON Object to Valid JSON Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, validation

I know this is already asked question but i don't get answer from any question previously asked...

My Problem is - Server sends a Array of JSON objects as String and i want to convert the string in to valid JSON array.

Example: Server sends like this

```
 '{
    "ts": "3170075",
    "eventid": 25,
    "oper_minutes": 48577,
    "time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z",
    "lto": "7200000",
    "package_name": "XXX",
    "timestamp": "1480660593188",
    "action_type": "1",
    "events": [{
        "device_name": 0,
        "key_category": 1,
        "eventid": 15,
        "ts": "2111"
     }, {
        "power_state": 3,
        "reason": 1,
        "eventid": 1,
        "ts": "2113"
     }]
}, {
    "ts": "3170084",
    "eventid": 25,
    "oper_minutes": 48577,
    "time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z",
    "lto": "7200000",
    "package_name": "XXXX",
    "timestamp": "1480660593218",
    "action_type": "1",
    "events": [{
        "device_name": 0,
        "key_category": 1,
        "eventid": 15,
        "ts": "2111"
     }, {
        "power_state": 3,
        "reason": 1,
        "eventid": 1,
        "ts": "2113"
     }]
}'
```

I want to convert it into valid array of two objects using pure javascript.

Example:

```
   [{
    "ts": "3170075",
    "eventid": 25,
    "oper_minutes": 48577,
    "time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z",
    "lto": "7200000",
    "package_name": "XXX",
    "timestamp": "1480660593188",
    "action_type": "1",
    "events": [{
        "device_name": 0,
        "key_category": 1,
        "eventid": 15,
        "ts": "2111"
     }, {
        "power_state": 3,
        "reason": 1,
        "eventid": 1,
        "ts": "2113"
     }]
}, {
    "ts": "3170084",
    "eventid": 25,
    "oper_minutes": 48577,
    "time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z",
    "lto": "7200000",
    "package_name": "XXX",
    "timestamp": "1480660593218",
    "action_type": "1",
    "events": [{
        "device_name": 0,
        "key_category": 1,
        "eventid": 15,
        "ts": "2111"
     }, {
        "power_state": 3,
        "reason": 1,
        "eventid": 1,
        "ts": "2113"
     }]
}]
```

I already tried JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, etc

No valid result as expected..

NOTE: This array of objects may be of any size, the server sometimes send 1000 objects and sometimes only 10 but as string. Should not take too much time to process.

Please help, i'm stuck with this for almost a day.. i'm using this in nodeJS so Only pure javaScript or with NPM libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON string you're sending is invalid because it should be encapsulated in [].

You could do :

```
var str = '{"ts": "3170075","eventid": 25,"oper_minutes": 48577,"time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z","lto": "7200000","package_name": "XXX","timestamp": "1480660593188","action_type": "1","events": [{"device_name": 0,"key_category": 1,"eventid": 15,"ts": "2111" }, {"power_state": 3,"reason": 1,"eventid": 1,"ts": "2113" }]}, {"ts": "3170084","eventid": 25,"oper_minutes": 48577,"time": "2016-12-02T06:36:36Z","lto": "7200000","package_name": "XXXX","timestamp": "1480660593218","action_type": "1","events": [{"device_name": 0,"key_category": 1,"eventid": 15,"ts": "2111" }, {"power_state": 3,"reason": 1,"eventid": 1,"ts": "2113"}]}';

    var obj = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`);
```

The errors you get trying to do it manually are because your original String is invalid as posted in your post (because of the newlines).

Comment: in cypress , when i pass --env flags = '{"config":"qa","userID":"user"}'  , config.env.flags is showing as {config:qa,userID:user} . any idea how to read or convert back to json ? JSON.stringify is returning undefined as this is not a valid json format. any help would be appreciated?